# AOP - Injecting a property with a dynamically computed value

Tags: aop, postsharp

(or "Using LocationInterceptionAspect and IInstanceScopedAspect together")

Using Postsharp I'm trying to inject a property into a target class using 'IntroduceMember' and then using the 'OnGetValue' functionality of LocationInterceptionAspect dynamically give it a value on inspection.

Originally I thought that I'd need two separate aspects, one for the field injection and one for the location interception but managed to combine the two by implementing the IInstanceScopedAspect interface and inheriting from LocationInterceptionAspect.

The problem is that if I set a breakpoint I will see the property that's been injected, but if I set another breakpoint in the OnGetValue method (that gets fired for each property on the class) I can't see it...

Here's some sample code:

```
[Serializable]
class DALDecoratorWrapper : LocationInterceptionAspect, IInstanceScopedAspect
{
    public override void OnGetValue(LocationInterceptionArgs args)
    {
        if (args.LocationName == "Type")
        {
            args.Value = "computed value here";
        }

        args.ProceedGetValue();
    }

    [IntroduceMember(OverrideAction = MemberOverrideAction.OverrideOrFail)]
    public String Type { get; set; }
```

I was also hoping there was a better way of doing this than overriding OnGetValue as that's called for each getter where really I want to only target the getter of the property that's been injected

Cheers